# Swift generic constructor

Tags: swift, generics

**The questions are embedded in comments** as well as here:

1. How can I define a default value for a generic T in parameter list?
2. When copying a parameter in Swift, is it pointers or objects?

   - XCode Beta 7 tells me I can't change "head", as it is a "let", see code
3. Any Swift-like way to while-loop checking for nil to avoid unwrapping?

Linked List implementation:

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public var data: T
    public var next: Node<T>?

    //1.
    //How can I define a default datatype for T?
    //In C++ I would let T ctor do it: "data: T = T()" gives 
    //error: 'T' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
    public init(data: T, next: Node<T>?)
    {
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
    }
}

func print<T>(head: Node<T>)
{
    var tmp = head  //2. Is this a copy of a pointer or an object?
    print(tmp.data)
    while(tmp.next != nil)  //3. Any Swiftier way to do it?
    {
        tmp = tmp.next!
        print(tmp.data)
    }
}

func insert<T>(head: Node<T>, _ value: T)
{
    var tmp = head
    while tmp.next != nil
    {
        tmp = tmp.next!
    }
    tmp.next = Node<T>(data: value, next: nil)
}

var head = Node<Int>(data: 1, next: nil)
insert(head, 2)
insert(head, 4)
insert(head, 8)
insert(head, 16)
print(head)
```

Also, any other comments? I'm very new to Swift

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**1.**

Generics is all about code safety without knowing the type on compile time. That means it would make no sense to initialise a generic type to something. However by declaring a protocol like

```
protocol Initializable {
    init()
}
```

, extending the types you want to use by doing

```
extension Int : Initializable {}
```

(maybe implement the `init()` method yourself) and declaring your node like

```
public class Node<T: Initializable>
```

you can use `T()` in your initialiser to create the initial value. Because now the compiler knows that this type does indeed have such an initialiser because it conforms to that protocol.

**2.**

Classes are **always** passed as a reference whereas structs are **always** copied

To be able to change an input value of a function it has to be declared as `inout` like

```
func insert<T>(inout head: Node<T>, _ value: T)
```

Then you also need to call the function like `insert(&head, 2)`

**3.**

You could write the loop like

```
while let next = tmp.next {
    tmp = next
    print(tmp.data)
}
```

**4.**

Swift is a beautiful language, and I strongly suggest you to use more Swiftier code in general.

The way you wrote those 2 methods is as if in C. You can put functions in classes and this is the optimal way to do it and it's also much simpler.

Not very important I admit, but this style of curly brackets is outdated

You don't need to declare a function as public if you don't really need it. And you only need it when writing a framework or something along those lines. The default behaviour (no access control modifier) is to have access to all your Swift files in the whole project.

This `Initializable` protocol I made here isn't really Swifty either

Brackets around `while (boolean)` are not needed and aren't Swifty

Named parameters are there for a reason: To make code more readable. Only remove them when you're absolutely sure that it's annoying and it's clear what the parameter represents.

I didn't want to do this originally but I redid your code in a much more Swifty way and I hope I can help you with that:

```
protocol DefaultValuable {
    static func defaultValue() -> Self
}

extension Int : DefaultValuable {
    static func defaultValue() -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}

class Node<T: DefaultValuable> {
    var data: T
    var next: Node<T>?

    init(data: T = T.defaultValue(), next: Node<T>? = nil) {
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
    }

    func printNode() {
        var tmp = self
        print(tmp.data)

        while let next = tmp.next {
            tmp = next
            print(tmp.data)
        }
    }

    func insert(value: T) {
        var tmp = self

        while let next = tmp.next {
            tmp = next
        }

        tmp.next = Node<T>(data: value)
    }
}

let head = Node<Int>()
head.insert(2)
head.insert(4)
head.insert(8)
head.insert(16)
head.printNode()
```

(Sorry for the kinda rant)

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much for the tips. I have no problem with all the comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't do this, in Swift. You could make `data` an optional, or overload `init` for specific types, but `self.data = T()` or similar isn't possible.
2. Variables for objects made from classes are always reference type in Swift, so basically pointers under the hood.
3. Your `print` function could be better written:

   ```
   func print<T>(head: Node<T>)
   {
       var tmp: Node<T>? = head
       while let currentNode = tmp
       {
           print(currentNode.data)
           tmp = tmp?.next
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer with checked mark is the best and detailed answer so far.

What I want to complement is my view of generic.

If I understand properly about the relationship among value, type, and type constructor in Swift.

Firstly, I think everything needed to be executed or manipulated are values, like `1,2,3`, `"I am a string"` or so.

Secondly, Types are types of values. There are two kinds of type, `Reference Type` and `Value Type`. `Reference Type` contains `class`, meaning the values are created by `class`, whereas `Value Type` contains `Struct` and `Enum`. In addition, I think `Function` and `closure` is reference type as well, even though they are immutable after they are created. How about `protocol`, my idea is that `protocol` is kind of type, even though sometimes `protocol` cannot be used as type when there are some `associatedtype` or `Self` used inside `protocol`, then `protocol` only can be used as `Type Constraint` in `Generic`.

The last one is `Generic` which is type constructor needing `generic parameters`, concrete type, meaning `Generic`, `Array<Element>` and `Element` is a `generic parameter` of `Generic` Array, is used to create a concrete `type`, `Array<Int>`, and then in turn to create a consumable `value`, `[1,2,3,4]`.

Therefore, if you want to use `Generic` as a normal `type` like some classes, `NSString`, `UILabel` or so, you must supply types as `generic parameters` to derive a concrete type beforehand.

### Updated

First of all, I apologize my statement about protocol as a type. It is not correct. Yes, protocol can behave like a type. But actually it is an abstract type interface which describe a group of behaviors conformers should implement. When there are some `associatedtype` and/or `Self constraint` used inside a protocol, it gained some generic characteristic that enable it to be more proper as `Type Constraint` with `where`, the additional condition, moreover powerfully extended its extension default implementation.

At the end of day, I see `protocol` as a wrapper which hasn't its own instance or value, but wraps a value of its conformer type, furthermore, `protocol extension` offers default behaviors as well.